# Is this Shunting Yard's fault or my own?

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, shunting-yard

Given the expression:

```
 1/2/3/4*5
```

It reaches the end of the expression and attempts to multiply out the 4 and 5 first WHICH IS WRONG because it begins to pop off the stack. I'm not necessarily doing RPN but just evaluating on the spot. How can I prevent this?

```
// Expression was completely read - so we should try and make sense of
// this now
while (operatorStack.size() != 0) {
    ApplyOperation(operatorStack, operandStack);
}
```

At this point, I begin to pop off operators and operations. Since multiplication and division have the same presence, they start with multiplication.

A trace:

```
1/2/3/4*5
Applying * to 5 and 4
Result: 20
Applying / to 20 and 3
Result: 3/20
Applying / to 3/20 and 2
Result: 40/3
Applying / to 40/3 and 1
Result: 3/40
```

Comment: How should we know? You've posted no code.

Comment: A basically silly question. The shunting yard algorithm has been working since 1961.

Comment: @MikeW Sorry, it was a general question. Allow me to add some context...

Comment: @EJP I've edited my question a bit to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a point in the shunting yard algorithm at which you compare the precedence of the operator at the top of the stack with the precedence of the operator in the input stream, and decide whether to pop the stack (evaluate the stacked operator, in your case), or push the new operator.

It makes a big difference if the comparison is `<` or `<=`. One of those will produce left-associativity, and the other will produce right-associativity. Since you're getting right-associativity and you want left-associativity, I'm guessing (without seeing your code) that 
you're using the wrong comparison operator.

By the way, your professor is quite correct. There is no need to explicitly produce RPN, and the evaluation algorithm will indeed pop the entire stack when it reaches the end of input. (The RPN algorithm would also do that; the evaluation algorithm is simply a shortcut.)

Comment: Brilliant! This was exactly the issue. How you knew is a bit insane. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What operatorStack? The RPN resulting from the shunting-yard algorithm is a *list,* not a stack. It is processed from left to right, not FIFO,

Comment: Hi, I was told by our professor we're using a variant of this. Upon further inspection, his is not quite the same. We were told to evaluate as we went - using precedence to pop operands back onto a stack. When you got to the end, pop them all back off in reverse orders... clearly this is a bad idea.

Comment: Sounds like your professor is producing true Polish (really Lukasiewicz) notation, somehow, then using a stack to reverse it. I can't see the point when the SYA already produces the right order. You don't even need the list/stack at all, you can just evaluate instead of producing output.

Comment: So, are you implying I should convert to a list and just read left to right? I think there might be side-effects..

Comment: I'm not 'implying' anything at all. I *explicitly stated* that you should process RPN left to right, and I also *explicitly stated* that you don't need either the second stack or a list.

Comment: Thanks. :) Another user has managed to get what was the issue - but you've helped me realize the true nature of what shunting yard does. +1